# Android Why does this line of code execute after the for loop?

Tags: android, for-loop, imagebutton

```
  btnSwitch2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                btnSwitch2.setImageResource(R.drawable.on);
                myVib.vibrate(50);
                strobeFlash();
            }
        });

    }
 private void strobeFlash(){        
            for(int i=0; i<10;++i){
                turnOnFlash2();
                turnOffFlash2();
            }
    }
```

The code above executes when a button is pressed, I would like to change the picture of the image button. However, when the button is pressed, the for loop executes first then the line above it

```
btnSwitch2.setImageResource(R.drawable.on);
```

executes. Is there something I'm doing that's causing the loop to execute completely first?

Answer (score 0):

Actually for loop execution is faster the then changing the image resource. You can add a postDelay() between the UI update and the for loop execution. 
It will solve the issue.

```
          btnSwitch2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    btnSwitch2.setImageResource(R.drawable.on);
                    myVib.vibrate(50);
                    handler=new Handler();
                    Runnable r=new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                strobeFlash();        

                            }
                    };
                    handler.postDelayed(r, 3000);

                }
            });

        }
        private void strobeFlash(){        
                for(int i=0; i<10;++i){
                    turnOnFlash2();
                    turnOffFlash2();
                }
        }
```

Comment: *Actually for loop execution is faster the then changing the image resource*  heheheehe .... seems like you do not understand UI thread, too ... UI thread is blocked in onClick ... so there will be no onDraw event ... so even if bitmap is decoded faster it will not show ...

Comment: ... and why `postDelay(...)` ?  `post(...)` is more proper here ... it should queue the runnable, so next time UI thread will be picking from the message queue it first should take the "onDraw" and then this runnable ...